# DATETIME vs LIKE to make a dynamic search SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to dynamically search for a date in my database according to my $data input.

Dates are stored as date-times and are usually displayed as ex: "2016-05-11".

With a MySql DB my clause was:

```
Select * From Table WHERE ( Table.date LIKE '$data%' )
```

So if the user enters "20" the results will be all dates that start with 20. If the user enters "2016-05" the results will be all dates that start with 2016-05, making my search perfectly working.

When deploying over a Sql Server 2008. I realized 2 things.

1) If i use the LIKE function as Such

```
Select * From Table WHERE ( Table.date LIKE '%$data$%')
```

The function will work for a value of "2016" , but would  return 0 results when a value of "2016-" is entered.

2) If i use the function DATETIME as such

```
Select * From Table WHERE ( DATEPART(year, Table.date) LIKE(OR)= '$data')
```

The function will return correct values when $data = 2016, but will return nil values when the $data = '201' for example, hence making it not dynamic.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is with the input validation.  If a user can input `20`, they can also input `'fred` or `2016-02-30`.

Comment: Im using ajax calls so if they enter Fred. They wont get results. That isnt a problem ? Am i not right ?

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversion is just bad, bad, bad -- in SQL or most other programming languages.

`LIKE` acts on strings.  If you want it to work on strings, then *explicitly* make sure that the parameters are strings.  This is true in MySQL and SQL Server.

If you want to use `LIKE` on the year, then use `DATENAME()` rather than `DATEPART()`:

```
WHERE DATENAME(year, Table.date) LIKE '$data'
```

However, I would encourage you to think about dates using date-based constructs, such as date ranges.

Comment: But, My input is a string! I explicitly tell the user to enter a YYYY-MM-DD string, and my search happens accordingly. So that isnt a problem !?

Comment: Almost every application out there that searched by date uses date ranges. Even if you've somehow come up with a better way to search for dates that no one else has ever thought of (doubtful), it's what people expect. When I go to an airline booking website and want to search by date I don't expect to put in "2016-06-" to search for flights in June. Also, how would one search for dates between 2016-05-18 and 2016-05-21?

Comment: @MakDo . . . Then *explicitly* convert the date value to a string, using `date_format()` or `convert()`.   All these methods, by the way, preclude the use of indexes -- implicit conversion and function calls generally interfere with index usage.

Comment: This way you wont be able to use the date information for any use other than "single value" search. e.g. any short of aggregated analysis or subsetting based on dates

Comment: @TomH. I was asking. Never said i created something no one ever thought of. Instead of your Ego comment. A coding what to do wouldve been better.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my stupid mistake. 
I needed to add a wildcard to my LIKE clause using DATEPART as such.

Select * From Table WHERE ( DATEPART(year, Table.date) LIKE = '$data%' ) .

Works perfectly.

But i would love other suggestions to simplify splitting $data into YYYY , MM , DD and then testing each element.

Answer (score 0):

I would strive to keep `Table.date` free of manipulation, so indexes are used.

Instead you can use a `CASE` expression to convert the search parameter to a date range by adding the missing parts:

Lower bound:

```
CASE LENGTH($data) 
 WHEN 8 THEN $data + '01'
 WHEN 7 THEN $data + '-01'
 WHEN 5 THEN $data + '01-01'
 WHEN 4 THEN $data + '-01-01'
 ELSE $data
END
```

Upper bound:

```
CASE LENGTH($data) 
 WHEN 8 THEN DATEADD(MONTH,$data + '01',1)
 WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(MONTH,$data + '-01',1)
 WHEN 5 THEN DATEADD(YEAR,$data + '01-01')
 WHEN 4 THEN DATEADD(YEAR,$data + '-01-01')
 ELSE DATEADD(DAY,$data,1)
END
```